# How to test SetTimeout function calld in VUE Created HOOK? using Vue utils - JEST

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I have an alert component which has a flag `isVisible`, this flag is becoming true when the component is created, and also in the created HOOK I have a `setTimeout` which starts if the component receives DESTROY boolean prop:

```
props: {
  destroy: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
}
```

```
data() {
  return {
    isVisible: false,
  }
}
```

```
created() {
  this.isVisible = true
  if (this.destroy) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.isVisible = false
    }, 2500)
  },
}
```

I am using VUE UTILS / JEST to test if the component disappears after `setTimeout` is over, I've tried:

```
test('Component dissapears after 2.5 seconds when it receives DESTROY prop', async () => {
  const component = wrapper.get('[data-test-id="info-alert-wrapper"]')
  await wrapper.setProps({
    destroy: true,
  })

  await wrapper.vm.$options.created.call()

  expect(component.isVisible()).toBeFalsy()
})
```

But it responds: `TypeError: Cannot set property 'isVisible' of undefined`

Can somebody help me with this? thank u! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your need to use fake timers here.
After all imports call `jest.useFakeTimers()`.
Then in test after mounting the component call `jest.runTimersToTime(2500)`. And after that you can do your assertions. Test example:

```
jest.useFakeTimers()

test('Component disappears after 2.5 seconds when it receives DESTROY prop', () => {
  const wrapper = shallowMount(YourSuperComponent, {
    propsData: {
      destroy: true
    }
  })
  jest.advanceTimersByTime(2500)
  expect(wrapper.vm.isVisible).toBe(false)
})
```

Comment: Glad the code helped!) Mark my post as an answer to your question then! ;)

Comment: Sorry, that was my first question :D i just markd ur answer :)

Comment: Updated the answer according to @deLiz's info :)

Answer (score 2):

Answer from @Eduardo is correct, just noting that Jest renamed **runTimersToTime()** to **advanceTimersByTime()** since Jest 22.0.0